# date is incompatible with int

Tags: sql

I get this error and although i tried to search for an existing answer, i could not implement is in mt query

so i have got :

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

This is my query :

```
Select   emp_desc, SUM(Price*Num_Of_Products) 
from     sales
Where    sale_date between 2014-01-01 and 2017-01-01
GRoup By emp_desc
```

any suggestions?
Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019011/sql-server-operand-type-clash-date-is-incompatible-with-int)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Single quotes around your date literals:

```
select 
    emp_desc
  , sum(Price * Num_Of_Products)
from sales
where sale_date >= '20140101' 
  and sale_date <  '20170101'
group by emp_desc
```

Also, `between` might not be doing what you think it is doing there.

Reference:

> The only truly safe formats for date/time literals in SQL Server, at least for `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, are: `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]` 
> - [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

- [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [#BackToBasics : Dating Responsibly - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/)

Comment: Thanks guys. appriciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

either you need to use apostrophes for your dates

```
Where sale_date between '2014-01-01' and '2017-01-01' GRoup By emp_desc
```

or the column sale_date is declared as int
so you would have to use

```
Where sale_date between 20140101 and 20170101 GRoup By emp_desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Above definitely works or just by adding single quotes, you can also try this way if date is stored in datetime format

```
Select   emp_desc, SUM(Price*Num_Of_Products) 
from     sales
Where    convert(varchar(10),sale_date,120)  between '2014-01-01' and '2017-01-01'
GRoup By emp_desc
```

Answer (score 0):

`2014-01-01` is an int - `2014` **minus** `1` **minus** `1`, or `2012`. If you surround these expressions with single quotes (`'`), they will become strings, and the implicit conversion from string to date should do the trick:

```
SELECT   emp_desc, SUM(price * num_of_products)
FROM     sales
WHERE    sale_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2017-01-01'
         -- Here ----------^----------^-----^----------^
GROUP BY emp_desc
```